# Using vue-test-utils to mount a simple component in a Jasmine test, getting "document not defined" error

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, jasmine, vue-test-utils

I've isolated my problem and recreated it in the code below, with just one test suite and a small number of dependencies. I'm using [Jasmine](https://jasmine.github.io/index.html) to run tests.

### Code and Configuration (isolated problem)

My **test spec file** (named `componentTest_spec.js`) contains the code below. The test is copied from the [Vue Test Utils help docs](https://next.vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/component-instance.html#a-simple-example):

```js
const mount = require("@vue/test-utils").mount;

describe("vue test utils", function () {

    it("renders a greeting", function () {
        const Comp = {
            template: `<div>{{ msg1 }} {{ msg2 }}</div>`,
            props: ["msg1"],
            data() {
                return {
                    msg2: "world"
                }
            }
        };

        const wrapper = mount(Comp, {
            props: {
                msg1: "hello"
            }
        });

        expect(wrapper.html()).toContain("hello world");
    });
});
```

My **`package.json`** looks like this (very small):

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/test-utils": "^2.0.0-rc.13",
    "jasmine": "^3.9.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.6"
  }
}
```

To run the above test, I run this **command** from the command line:

```
npx jasmine componentTest_spec.js
```

---

### Error

When I run the above

```
Message:
   ReferenceError: document is not defined
 Stack:
   ReferenceError: document is not defined
       at mount (C:\projectfolder\node_modules\@vue\test-utils\dist\vue-test-utils.cjs.js:7625:14)
       at UserContext.<anonymous> (C:\projectfolder\componentTest_spec.js:16:25)
       at <Jasmine>
       at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:461:21)
```

The ReferenceError is being thrown somewhere inside the `mount` command, far as I can tell.

---

### Questions

What is wrong with the above code or configuration? Why am I getting this error when running a test from the Vue Test Utils website with minimal configuration? How can I get this test to run (roughly as is, mounting a simple component) using Jasmine?

Comment: You run it with Jasmine *test runner*. It runs tests in Node that doesn't have browser APIs. If you really want to use Jasmine for some reason, use Karma runner